# TypeError: (0 , _analytics.analytics) is not a function) google analytics react native

Tags: react-native

In react native app , I am using firebase google analytics.

The problem is in tracking screens, I follow [this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/screen-tracking)  , however I am having
[this error .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKrEe.png)

`TypeError: (0 , _analytics.analytics) is not a function).`

And the [Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Fag.jpg).

My appcontainer file (drawer.js) :

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Feed  from '../components/Home';
import {FeedStack}  from './stack';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  {analytics }from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
 {
   Feed: FeedStack
 },
);

function getActiveRouteName(navigationState) {
     if (!navigationState) {
       return null;
     }
     const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];

     if (route.routes) {
       return getActiveRouteName(route);
     }
     return route.routeName;
 }

const AppContainer =createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
export default () => {
    return <AppContainer
        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState, action) => {
            const currentRouteName = getActiveRouteName(currentState);
            const previousRouteName = getActiveRouteName(prevState);

            if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
      analytics().setCurrentScreen(currentRouteName, currentRouteName);
            }
          }}
    />
}
```

My app.js :

```
import Feed from './src/components/Home';
import HomePage from './src/components/homeEpaper';
import Navigator from './src/navigator/drawer';

import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default function App() {

    return (

      <Navigator />
    )

}
```

I tried also  import  analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
and i got this error. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exKGg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you didn't follow the docs 100% to the point :)

In your code you do:

```
import  {analytics }from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
```

However if you look at this file: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/packages/analytics/lib/index.js you'll see that there is no named export analytics. What you do when you type `import {analytics}` is importing a named export: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Since there is no named export analytics in that file the value for analytics is undefined and you get the error you describe.

I should type (as written in the linked example):

```
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
```

Comment: I tried that and I got similar error, can you check above I attached a screenshot?

Comment: The version of analytics you use no longer has the setCurrentScreen funciton. Instead you should use logScreenView

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/commit/18f5b0f7e65a3bddc92d3d23e31efb42a518ec12
```
    analytics().logScreenView({
      screen_class: screenName,
      screen_name: screenName,
    })
```

Comment: Ok thanks the error is gone, i will wait 24 hours to see if the screens appear in google console.

Comment: Cool! Don't forget to mark as "answer" if all is good :)

Answer (score 5):

if you're using `setCurrentScreen` method, then you need to use the following

**package.jsom**

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^10.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.4.0",
```

**Incorrect**

```
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
.
.
.
analytics().setCurrentScreen('SignUpScreen');`
```

**Correct**

```
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
.
.
.
// Google Firebase Analytics
analytics().logScreenView({
    screen_name: 'SignUpScreen',
    screen_class: 'SignUpScreen'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In new update `setCurrentScreen` is no longer present. Use other functions to log.